# Differential equation plot

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Do you know some books or booklets for beginning the study of how to do a differential equation plot? I need something with solved exercises and not to hard ones because I attend the first calculus course and the topics are not so difficult yet. :)
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean slope fields? That should be in the first chapter of any standard undergraduate text of a first course in differential equations.

Comment: Do you know some title to suggests me?

Comment: Like I said - any standard text. For example, Zill's _A First Course in Differential Equations_.

Answer (score 0):

Most calculus texts have a chapter or at least a section or two on differential equations. 
you may as well check "You Tube" for videos about vector fields or direction fields or phase portraits of differential equations.